# Disable centerMode if first or last slide is active - Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I have Slick slider in Wordpress single post's header. I am trying to disable `centerMode` if the first or last slide is active. I am trying to do it in this way:

```
let slider = $('.templateOverview-slider .slick-slide');
if (slider.first().hasClass('slick-current')) {
    $('.templateOverview-slider').slick('slickSetOption', 'centerMode', false);
} else if (slider.last().hasClass('slick-current')) {
    $('.templateOverview-slider').slick('slickSetOption', 'centerMode', false);
}
```

But `centerMode` is not disabled. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong, and how can I disable `centerMode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just need to pass a fourth parameter to your `slick()` calls so that the UI is refreshed.

```
$('.templateOverview-slider').slick('slickSetOption', 'centerMode', false, true);
```

From the Slick docs:

> slickSetOption
>
> **option :** string, **value :** depends on option, **refresh :** boolean -
> Sets an individual value live. Set refresh to true if it's a UI update.